# IDeepCopy Interface java

Tags: java, interface, copy

i have some troubles with understanding the following:
I should implement an Interface called IDeepCopy.

Description "This Interface is needed since the Cloneable interface provided by Java does not redeclare the clone method of Object. We want to use it as bounded type for generic classes so this additional interface is needed.
We have chosen to use an IDeepCopy interface to make handling of copying/cloning objects simpler. Classes that implement this interface should construct a copy of object by either invoking a private copy constructor, or by creating a new object of the same class and setting its values accordingly. Keep in mind, that attributes of classes should also be copied (if they implement the IDeepCopy interface) in the same way, before they are set on the copied object.
IDeepCopy deepCopy()"

I declared the Interface but I don't really know how I have to implement the method accordingly.

My idea is the following (implementation of the method in a sub class):

```
public SimpleProduct deepCopy(){
    return new SimpleProduct(x,x);
}
```

But how can I set set the attributes if I don't get an Object as parameter in deepCopy?

Answer (score 1):

From the description, it sounds like you're just supposed to pass in any the corresponding values from the original instance to the new one, calling `.deepCopy()` if applicable. e.g.

```
public class SimpleProduct implements IDeepCopy {

    private final int x;
    private final OtherClass y;

    public SimpleProduct(int x, OtherClass y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public SimpleProduct deepCopy() {
        return (y instanceof IDeepCopy) ? new SimpleProduct(x, ((IDeepCopy)y).deepCopy()) : new SimpleProduct(x, y);
    }
}
```

**Edit:** updated `deepCopy` implementation with the suggestion from @c0der in comments

Comment: I would check if `y` implements `IDeepCopy` before `y.deepCopy()`

Comment: @c0der, if it doesn't implement it, it wont compile.

Comment: That's right. To make the example more generic you can use `return (y instanceof IDeepCopy) ? new SimpleProduct(x, (IDeepCopy)y.deepCopy()); : new SimpleProduct(x, y);`

Comment: I see your point.  If `OtherClass` doesn't implement it, but a subclass of it did, and the subclass was passed into the constructor of the original instance, then you would have to check for it first and cast it to call it.  I'll update my example for this, but don't ask me to write one for a class with a constructor like `public ComplexProduct(OtherClass1 x, List<OtherClass2> y, Map<OtherClass3, OtherClass4> z) {...}

Comment: (0: Up to you. I upvoted it anyhow. Maybe the comment is good enough. (For copying multiple constructor arguments I would use a method to check each, and return the appropriate value)